# JavaScript: JSON schema to validate another JSON schema

Tags: javascript, json, validation, jsonschema

I'm facing right now an application which needs to validate a form with a definition of JSON Schema inside.

I would want to know if there's a `validator schema` for `JSON` Schema on JavaScript

For example:

```js
let validate = schemaValidator.validate('{"title": "Example Schema","type": "object","properties": {"firstName": {"type": "string"},"lastName": {"type": "string"},"age": {"description": "Age in years","type": "integer","minimum": 0}},"required": ["firstName", "lastName"]}', metaSchema);
```

Formatted JSON

```js
{
  "title": "Example Schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "age": {
      "description": "Age in years",
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 0
    }
  },
  "required": ["firstName", "lastName"]
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Not sure but `JSON.parse` might help. It will throw error for any invalid JSON.

Comment: Are you asking for a library?

Comment: *"JSON schema for validate JSON schema"* - You  seem to be asking for a schema to validate another schema - is that what you mean? Or do you mean that you want a way to validate that a given JSON string matches the structure of the JSON shown in the question?

Comment: yes, I would need a schema to validate another schema, exacty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Schema Draft v4](http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema) is itself a JSON Schema you can use for validation of JSON Schemas.